# Play Framework : Lining up a FakeRequest with an temporary file action wrapped in maxLength

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, playframework-2.2

Trying to test a play controller, but caught in their super clever meta-programming tar-pit.

How do I line up a `FakeRequest` with a temporary file parsing action wrapped with a `maxLength`? :

```
trait FileActionUtils { self : Controller =>
  implicit class ByteSizeHelper(base : Int) {
    def KB = base * 1024
    def MB = base * 1024 * 1024
  }

  def singleSizeCappedFileAction(size: Int, filename: String)(fileHandler : (File) => Result) = {
    Action(maxLength(size, parser = parse.multipartFormData)) {
      _.body match {
        case Right(body) =>
          body.file(filename) match {
            case Some(file) =>
              fileHandler(file.ref.file)
            case None =>
              BadRequest.withHeaders("message" -> "\"file\" not encoded in multipart body.")
          }
        case Left(error) =>
          BadRequest.withHeaders("message" -> "file is too large.")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying :

```
  ....
  val body = new MultipartFormData(Map(),
    List(
      FilePart("file", "file1.mpp", Some("Content-Type: multipart/form-data"),   TemporaryFile("test/fixtures/file1.mpp"))
    ),
    Nil,Nil
  )
  val request = FakeRequest().withMultipartFormDataBody(body)
  val result = controller.parseProjectFile("").apply(request)

  println(contentAsString(result))
  ....
```

I'm expecting a string or something I can work with on the other side as the test shows. Plus, I know for a fact the controller is working fine.